# ArcGIS 10 (SP 3) - Geometric Network - which features are moved?

Tags: snapping, arcgis-10.0, geometric-network

In ArcGIS 9.3 Geometric Network, you can select which features can be moved when snapping.

In ArcGIS 10 (SP 3) this functionality has disappeared and you either choose to have snap tolerance or not. 
Does anyone know why this functionality is no longer available? When snapping 3 feature classes to create a geometric network, how do we know which feature class has moved? We only want 1 of the 3 feature classes to move.
Does anyone know how we can define which feature class is to move (and snap) to the other feature classes?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many reasons why I keep a copy of 9.3.1 on at least one PC.  If it ain't broke . . .

The functionality has indeed disappeared from inside the geometric network wizard.  ESRI now recommends that you fix all snapping issues before building the geometric network.  It's quite a bit more complicated but it can be done.

`If your data requires a lot of changes to ensure coincidence, consider first creating a Topology on your data to find and fix the errors. Topology contains an exhaustive set of rules to check for data integrity violations and a suite of tools and commands to correct any errors. Creating your geometric network prior to correcting spatial and attribute errors can often lead to more work when correcting the errors. Because network features have special behavior and are aware of what they are connected to, correcting issues such as overshoots and undershoots can take more steps and time once the geometric network is in place. For this reason, we recommend that building your geometric network be done after correcting spatial errors.`

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002r00000008000000